# Criterion for a bounded linear operator to be compact

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces. $T\colon X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator.

How can I prove that $T$ is compact if and only if there is $\lbrace x_n^*\rbrace\subset X^*$ such that $\|x_n^*\|\to 0$ and $\|T(x)\|\leq \operatorname{sup}_n|x_n^*(x)|$ for every $x\in X$?

Comment: Homework?  What have you done so far?  Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: So, if it's the "only if" portion of the proposition that's giving you trouble, I take it you're struggling with showing: "if T is compact, then there is...for every $x \in X$"?  Have you managed to confirm the converse?  Many users are more motivated to help/give hints/answers when you clarify what exactly you're stuck on, and show some of your efforts...so perhaps you can elaborate (edit your question, if possible, or reply to some comments?)

Comment: Are you assuming $X$ is separable?

Answer (score 2):

See theorem 1 in [A characterization of compact linear mappings. T. Terzioglu](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01222542#page-1)

Click there "look inside" to see the proof.